Why does a private method get called from reference type while public method gets called from object type in Java?
I understand that private methods can't be overridden in Java, but I'm confused about method resolution behavior. Here's my code:
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Sub();
        m.sing();
        System.out.println(m.foo()+"");
    }

    public void sing(){
        System.out.println("hohoho");
    }
    
    private boolean foo(){
        return false;
    }
    
}

class Sub extends Main{
    
    public boolean foo(){
        return true;
    }
    
    public void sing(){
        System.out.println("lalala");
    }
}

According to my assumption, as the m object type is Sub and it's reference type is Main, it is the object type (Sub) that decides which method to be invoked at runtime and in this case, I assumed both the function calls to be invoked from Sub class.
But the output is:
lalala

false

Note that, when I call sing method, Sub Class method is invoked and when I call foo method Main Class method is invoked.
While calling sing() it makes sense that Sub's implementation is run because it is implicitly overriding the Main's sing(). I also understand that foo() methods in both classes are standalone and Sub does not inherit and override foo().
My question here is when calling foo method, what is stopping java to run Sub class foo() ?(this is based on my assumption that it's object type that determines the method to run not the reference type, but observation shows otherwise)
Is my assumption fundamentally wrong ?

"Actual behavior: The code prints true." - Interesting, it prints false on my machine, and on https://www.w3schools.com/java/tryjava.asp, and on https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler. Which compile/runtime are you using?

It prints false

Prints false for me as well (the expected behavior).

my guess, you didn't recompile your code after a change. just wrote the same code here (not a copy paste, but still the same), it prints false.

@Sweeper I'm not sure this a duplicate, at least not based on this question's contents. Given the OP expects the private method to be called, they seem to understand that private methods cannot be overridden. It appears they're confused because their example is showing the opposite (though like Stultuske, I suspect the OP is not executing the code they think they are).

@Slaw Yeah I realised my mistake immediately afterwards. I left it closed anyway because it is not reproducible/no MRE. I am happy to reopen it once it has been edited to include a MRE.

"the expected behavior"... really?. I don't think we can talk about an “expected exit”, I think we are starting from a very particular place... “malpractice, which compiles”, overwriting a private method is not a good idea, it produces outputs that for some may be logical and for others not, and it is so obvious, that if in the example above I use: Main sub = new Sub(); and System.out.println( sub.foo() ); it prints “false” and if I use: Sub sub = new Sub(); and System.out.println( sub.foo() ); it prints “true”.

Why are you now expecting the opposite as before the edit? Are you always expecting the opposite of what (you think) is happening?

Your edit changes your question so that now the expected behavior is the opposite of what you previously expected. That makes the duplicate more accurate. That said, the compiler chooses the method to call based on the reference type (i.e., the type of the variable). The reference type of m is Main. At run-time, if the selected method is subject to dynamic dispatch, then the JVM will choose the correct method based on the run-time type (i.e., the type of the actual object). Private methods are not subject to dynamic dispatch. Thus, your code executes Main::foo and not Sub::foo.

Java has no concepts of “object type” and “reference type”.
